# Visual studio keeps on popping Save as dialog box whenever I try to create or change existing table in Microsoft SQLClient

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have been trying to get rid of this problem but seems like there's no solution to this, my visual studio keeps on popping save as dialog box whenever I try to make any changes to the tables in Microsoft SQL client. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package but that didn't help either.
btw i'm using it in c#.net project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using the IDE tool of vs to do database operations?

Comment: @Housheng-MSFT yes I am

Answer (score 0):

First, the registry modification solution

Find the registry and delete the following 2 items
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger

Also delete the following registry keys on 64-bit operating systems:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger

2. Make changes in the visual studio menu

Enter visual studio, select [Tools]->[Options], click [Mode], in the [Real-time] tab, uncheck the three checkmarks of [Native] [Script] [Managed] and it will be ok, restart the computer

3. In the IIS website properties, main directory, application configuration, and debugging, just remove the first check mark, which may be the point of the customer's technical debugging program. restart the server

Hope it helps you thank you